# How to find out which encryption method was used here?

Tags: encryption, hash, password-encryption, password-hash

I have a user table in a database that contains the following columns:

> KeyEnc: 05992DB2BC2055946C299459AF8A4B3F 
> Password: X/i9vH5oXcBLAn+MWAIIJQ==

Considering that the password is known for any hash pair, is there any way to find out which authentication method was used?

**[UPDATE]** 
Below are some informations, tests and attempts:

1. In terms of information, I am trying to discover the method to integrate the database of these systems with an API that I am creating and I have full authorization to the database. Unfortunately I don't have access to the source code.
2. I tried to decode the hashes both as MD5 and base64, respectively, but I was not successful.
3. I believe that KeyEnc is the password decryption key, but I'm not sure.
4. As I said, passwords are known, but the method is not.
5. The database is MSSQL and the backend is Java, the tbm frontend is java and I believe it uses the PrimeFaces framework.

Comment: Without more details the answer is "no"

Comment: The trailing `==` indicates a base64 encoding, after decoding you can see the length of the binary value, the rest is try and error.

Comment: @MichaelFehr, these are all pertinent details that I have, what do you think would be most necessary?

Comment: @martinstoeckli incredible as it may seem, it is not recognized as base64 when it has to do decode, in the same way that the first KEY that looks like MD5 is not MD5 itself.

Comment: @JoismarBraga - Who says this is MD5? It can be anything, even a home made algorithm, we cannot tell from the binary value.